# Error en PHP cuando quiero seleccionar y comprobar una tabla

Tags: php, sql, base-de-datos, mysqli

Estoy haciendo un pequeño CRUD, y estoy teniendo un problema a la hora de querer enviar los datos para actualizar (unos datos de la tabla)

La tabla es la siguiente:

id | user_name_ | user_pass | name | user_state

2__talil_________Gsdf________45345__1

(Los guiones bajos solo son para que se ubiquen como esta los datos en la tabla y cual va en cada uno)

Y yo necesito seleccionar los datos para verificar que el "user_name_" y el "id" para verificar a la hora de enviar los datos actualizados, si son diferentes a los datos ya subidos en la base, pues que lo actualice, y si son diferentes que no lo actualice y que los deje normal, como estaban

El codigo que me da error es el siguiente:

```
    [Linea 18] $query = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM table_users WHERE (`user_name_` = $user_name AND `id` != $user_id)");

    [Linea 20] $result = mysqli_fetch_array($query);
```

Entonces cuando envío el formulario con los datos actualizados me da el siguiente error en la linea 18 y no se me actualizan los datos de la tabla:

```
    Fatal error: Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: Unknown column 'talil' in 'where clause' in C:\xampp\htdocs\...\...\...\edit_users.php:18 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\...\...\...\edit_users.php(18): mysqli_query(Object(mysqli), 'SELECT * FROM t...') #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\...\...\...\edit_users.php on line 18
```

Answer (score 1):

Taliloco ponele comillas a $user_name es un string

```
$query = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM table_users WHERE `user_name_` = '$user_name' AND `id` != $user_id");
```